# Make fields required using array in angular form control?

Tags: angular, forms, frontend, formgroups

I have a form in `Angular`, in which I used two arrays(having 4 fields) as controls.
User can click `+` icon to add more indexes to any of the arrays and fill the values.

How to make the fields of that array `required`. Whenever I check if the controls are empty or not every time it shows that there are empty indexes in the arrays.
How to check whether it is empty or not?

Comment: have tried adding required property to the input field ?

Comment: Can you add a demo code with the problem on stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/
And I hope you have already referred online documentation of angular forms : https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Reactive form (instead of a template-driven form), you can programmatically add any type of AbstractControl to your form.

Assuming that clicking on the `+` calls a method, you could have a it create a new FormGroup and push that to your FormArray (again, assuming that's the structure of your form):

```js
public addIndexToArray() {
  const formGroup = new FormGroup({
    index: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    // any other fields
  })
  this.myFormArray.push(formGroup)
}
```

Now that `index` FormControl will be marked as invalid if the user touches the FormControl but does not enter a value. `Validators` is part of the native Angular FormsModule and it provides a number of helpful tools.